# Sorting Dictionary of struct with CLLocationCoordinate2D by proximity to current location

Tags: swift

I have a struct that defines the following parameters

```
struct City {
    let apiName: String
    let coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

And I have created a Dictionary that I would like to sort by proximity from the user's current location

```
let cities: [String: City] = [
    "Bilbao": City(apiName: "bilbao", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(43.263459), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(-2.937053))),
    "Madrid": City(apiName: "madrid", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(40.416775), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(-3.703790))),
    "New York": City(apiName: "new_york", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(40.730610), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(-73.935242)))]
```

What would be the best option to sort that Dictionary without iterating with a for loop and not using a temporary array and sorting it? I've tried a `map` and `sort(by:)` with no luck and I would like to understand the shortest way of doing this.

Comment: show your code with sorting

Answer (score 0):

If for example the current location is,

```
let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(-60), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(40.8))
```

Then you can sort the `cities` based on `currentLocation` using **`distance(from:)`** like so,

```
let sortedCities = cities.sorted { (city1, city2) -> Bool in
    let diff1 = CLLocation(latitude: city1.value.coordinates.latitude, longitude: city1.value.coordinates.longitude).distance(from: currentLocation)
    let diff2 = CLLocation(latitude: city2.value.coordinates.latitude, longitude: city2.value.coordinates.longitude).distance(from: currentLocation)
    return diff1 < diff2
}
```

**Output:**

```
["Madrid": City(apiName: "madrid", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(40.416775), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(-3.703790))),
 "Bilbao": City(apiName: "bilbao", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(43.263459), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(-2.937053))),
 "New York": City(apiName: "new_york", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(40.730610), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(-73.935242)))]
```